# How to detect if a psudo-element (::after) was clicked in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, pseudo-element

I am trying to detect click events on an elements `::after` pseudo element.

I'm hoping something like this is possible:

```
//css
div:after{
  content:"X";
  display:block;
}

//jsx
class PsudoExample  extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div onAfterClick={() => {}}>

    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like a solution that doesn't involve the use of `document.queryselector` or something like that.

Comment: what is `onAfterClick`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to distinguish click events from an element and it's pesduo element(s) - the same event handler will fire when the user clicks on either.

One thing you can do though is use CSS to disable [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the host element, while allowing `pointer-events` on the element's pseduo element(s). That would give you a "half-way-there" mechanism for detecting clicks on pseduo element(s) only:

```
div:after{
  content:"X";
  display:block;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

div{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

With that, you would then use the regular `onClick` handler which should now only fire when the `::after` element is clicked:

```
class PseudoExample extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div onClick={() => { console.log("after clicked"); }}>
    I host a pseduo elements
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a click handler on the parent, but that won't tell you that the click was exactly on the "x" button.

Pseudo elements are meant to be used for decoration only. That's why you wouldn't need to write HTML for them and they are fully written in CSS.

If you have an "X" button that does something, you are better off adding a button element for it. Pseudo elements are not made for this. They are also not accessible (cannot have keyboard focus).

```js
class PseudoExample extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.close} type="button" class="close"/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  close = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PseudoExample/>, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```css
.close {
  border: none;
}

.close:after {
  content: "X";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main/>
```

I hate "you are doing it wrong" answers too. But in this case I think a small change (hopefully it's small in your case) is a much better option.

Comment: Feel free to revert the edit, just thought a fully-functioning demo might be nice here

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleClick = (item, e) => {
 let divLength = 210; // depends on your width
 if(e.nativeEvent.layerX < divLength) {
  //your code goes here
 } else {
  console.log("clicked after")
}


return (
  <div onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Click me</div>
)
```

**e.nativeEvent.layerX** returns the width of the clicked area of the element from left to right.